# How to mock UmbracoContext for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, umbraco, rhino-mocks

I am writing unit tests for ASP.NET MVC application using RhinoMocks and Umbraco. For this I need to mock UmbracoContext, and so used below code.
But Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current throws ArgumentNullException. Please suggest resolution for this:

```
var contextBase = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
var session = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
var server = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

contextBase.Stub(ctx => ctx.Request).Return(request);
contextBase.Stub(ctx => ctx.Response).Return(response);
contextBase.Stub(ctx => ctx.Session).Return(session);
contextBase.Stub(ctx => ctx.Server).Return(server);

var umbracoCtx = UmbracoContext.EnsureContext(contextBase, Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.Current);
```

Comment: There isn't much by way of running Umbraco in testable framework, but this is a great article, particularly for getting umbracoContext http://justthisguy.co.uk/unit-testing-umbraco/ You may need to do some work to get it to work with your framework of choice though

Comment: I recently released this helper to mock the Umbraco context along with unit testing examples. You can find out more on this approach at: https://github.com/garydevenay/Umbraco-Context-Mock

Answer (score 0):

the articles on the Internet doesn't really help with mocking umbraco context.
This is how we've done it with nSubstitute, but I'm sure you can convert it to other mocking libraries

```
public static IUmbracoContextFactory GetIUmbracoContextFactory()
{
    EnsureTestServicesForUmbraco();

    //IUmbracoContext
    var umbracoContext = Substitute.For<IUmbracoContext>();
    _ = umbracoContext.CleanedUmbracoUrl.Returns(new Uri("http://example.com"));
    _ = umbracoContext.OriginalRequestUrl.Returns(new Uri("http://example.com"));
    _ = umbracoContext.Content.Returns(Substitute.For<IPublishedContentCache>());
    _ = umbracoContext.Media.Returns(Substitute.For<IPublishedMediaCache>());
    _ = umbracoContext.Domains.Returns(Substitute.For<IDomainCache>());

    //media
    var media = GetMediaWithCrops();
    _ = umbracoContext.Media!.GetAtRoot().Returns(new[] { media });

    //content
    var root = Substitute.For<IPublishedContent>();
    _ = umbracoContext.PublishedRequest.Returns(GetPublishedRequest(root));
    _ = umbracoContext.Content!.GetAtRoot().Returns(new[] { root });

    //IUmbracoContextFactory
    var umbracoContextAccessor = new UmbracoContextTextAccessor(umbracoContext);
    var reference = new UmbracoContextReference(umbracoContext, true, umbracoContextAccessor);
    var factory = Substitute.For<IUmbracoContextFactory>();
    _ = factory.EnsureUmbracoContext().Returns(reference);

    return factory;
}

public static void EnsureTestServicesForUmbraco()
{
    var umbracoContextAccessor = Substitute.For<IUmbracoContextAccessor>();

    _ = umbracoContextAccessor.TryGetUmbracoContext(out _)
        .Returns(x =>
        {
            x[0] = Substitute.For<IUmbracoContext>();
            return true;
        });

    var serviceProvider = Substitute.For<IServiceProvider>();
    var publishedUrlProvider = Substitute.For<IPublishedUrlProvider>();

    _ = publishedUrlProvider.GetUrl(
        Arg.Any<IPublishedContent>(),
        Arg.Any<UrlMode>()).Returns(new Fixture().Create<Uri>().AbsoluteUri);

    _ = publishedUrlProvider.GetMediaUrl(
        Arg.Any<IPublishedContent>(),
        Arg.Any<UrlMode>()).Returns(new Fixture().Create<Uri>().AbsoluteUri);

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IPublishedUrlProvider>()
        .Returns(publishedUrlProvider);

    var variationContextAccessor = Substitute.For<IVariationContextAccessor>();
    _ = variationContextAccessor.VariationContext.Returns(new VariationContext("*"));

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IVariationContextAccessor>()
        .Returns(variationContextAccessor);

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IPublishedModelFactory>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IPublishedModelFactory>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IUserService>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IUserService>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IUmbracoContextAccessor>()
        .Returns(umbracoContextAccessor);

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<ISiteDomainMapper>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<ISiteDomainMapper>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IExamineManager>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IExamineManager>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IFileService>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IFileService>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IOptions<WebRoutingSettings>>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IOptions<WebRoutingSettings>>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IContentTypeService>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IContentTypeService>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IPublishedValueFallback>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IPublishedValueFallback>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IMediaTypeService>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IMediaTypeService>());

    _ = serviceProvider
        .GetService<IMemberTypeService>()
        .Returns(Substitute.For<IMemberTypeService>());

    StaticServiceProvider.Instance = serviceProvider;
}

private static PublishedRequest GetPublishedRequest(IPublishedContent publishedContent)
{
    return new PublishedRequest(
        _fixture.Create<Uri>(),
        _fixture.Create<string>(),
        publishedContent,
        _fixture.Create<bool>(),
        Substitute.For<ITemplate>(),
        Substitute.For<DomainAndUri>(
            _fixture.Create<Domain>(),
            _fixture.Create<Uri>()),
        _fixture.Create<string?>(),
        _fixture.Create<string>(),
        _fixture.Create<int>(),
        Substitute.For<IReadOnlyList<string>>(),
        Substitute.For<IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>>(),
        _fixture.Create<bool>(),
        _fixture.Create<bool>());
}

public static MediaWithCrops GetMediaWithCrops()
{        
    var publishedValueFallback = Substitute.For<IPublishedValueFallback>();
    var publishedContent = Substitute.For<IPublishedContent>();
    var image = Substitute.For<Image>(publishedContent, publishedValueFallback);
    var imageCropperValue = Substitute.For<ImageCropperValue>();

    var media = Substitute.For<MediaWithCrops>(
        image,
        publishedValueFallback,
        imageCropperValue);

    return media;
}
```